# CULEBRA: Empty device list

Tags: android, python, adb, androidviewclient

I want to create a AVD using Culebra and ADB, but I think that isn't the correct way, maybe I need to use SKD Android.

**OS:** Windows 10

***ADB is running***:

```
netstat -an | findstr 5037
  TCP    127.0.0.1:5037         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
```

***Running Culebra:***

*AndroidViewClient-master\tools>python culebra -G*

```
Empty device list, will wait 60 secs for devices to appear
........TIMEOUT HANDLER 3
Exception in thread Thread-4:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 1073, in run
    self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\androidviewclient-15.1.2-py2.7.egg\com\dtmilano\android\adb\adbclient.py", line 203, in timeoutHandler
    raise Timer.TimeoutException("Timer %d has expired" % timerId)
TimeoutException: Timer 3 has expired
```

Is *Culebra* and *ADB* enough to create a AVD?

Comment: You should see your device or avd when you run `adb devices`, then you can use `culebra` to connect to it. I'm not sure what you mean by *create AVD* but `culebra` **uses** them, it does not **create**

Comment: In the output you show, `culebra` is correctly waiting for some device to appear in `adb`

Comment: right, I understood that I need to use a SDK manager to create this AVD. I installed `AndroidStudio` and created an AVD. Is that the correct way?

Comment: Correct, once you have your AVD or device, you run `adb devices` to verify it's seen and then `culebra` will find it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create your AVD or connect your Android device first (i.e. via USB).

Then, run `adb` to verify they are connected

```
demo: $ adb devices
List of devices attached
emulator-5554   device
```

when they are, like in the previous example where `emulator-5554` is **online**, you can now run `culebra`. If you add `-V` (verbose), you will see the actual device being connected

```
demo: $ culebra -GV
Connecting to a device with serialno=.* with a timeout of 60 secs...
Connected to device with serialno=.*
Actual device serialno=emulator-5554
```

you will see `culebra` window (which would look much like your emulator window)

[image]

and as usual, the `python` script is generated

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Copyright (C) 2013-2018  Diego Torres Milano
Created on 2018-04-12 by Culebra v15.1.2
                      __    __    __    __
                     /  \  /  \  /  \  /  \ 
____________________/  __\/  __\/  __\/  __\_____________________________
___________________/  /__/  /__/  /__/  /________________________________
                   | / \   / \   / \   / \   \___
                   |/   \_/   \_/   \_/   \    o \ 
                                           \_____/--<
@author: Diego Torres Milano
@author: Jennifer E. Swofford (ascii art snake)
"""
...
```